# jenkins - Connection error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit

I am trying to standup my jenkins instance that can talk to my gerrit instances over Gerrit Trigger.

I am seeing the below error while testing connection:
Connection error : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.UnknownHostException:

I have placed the public key for the user I am trying to connect with.
From the jenkins host I tested the ssh connectivity and login over ssh key.

ssh -vT review02-gerrit -p 29418

****    Welcome to Gerrit Code Review    ****

Hi NetDevOps gerrit, you have successfully connected over SSH.

Unfortunately, interactive shells are disabled.
  To clone a hosted Git repository, use:

Not sure why the same user through jenkins application is not able to connect to gerrit host

Comment: Have you tried to use ip address of the gerrit server instead of the host name?

Comment: yes. I can rule out the dns resolution part. When trying to do ssh -vT -l username gerrit instance from jenkins. It goes through successfully. Also for the ipaddress part, I modified /etc/hosts file to add the resolution for gerrit host. The interesting part is, when trying the REST connection options, it goes through. But apparently I am not able to get it going by REST api alone. It looks like for the gerrit trigger plugin, it needs ssh connectivity from jenkins to gerrit over 29418(default gerrit port).

Comment: @arjundevops were you able to figure out a solution for this?

Comment: Yeah i'm stuck on this at the moment, struggling to make the known host's public key as part of the ssh connection